# problemas con variables de session laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

Estoy intentando hacer un timer.

Para esto primero capturo la hora en la que se sirve la pagina.

```
if(!$request->session()->has('timer')){
   $request->session()->put('timer', Carbon::now());
}
```

El problema viene cuando intento reescribir la variable de sesión o cuando intento eliminarla.

```
$diff = Carbon::now()->diffInSeconds($request->session('timer'));

if($diff > 60){
  // aqui no importa si la elimino o la sobre escribo El valor al final no lo cambia.
  $request->session()->put('timer', Carbon::now());
}
```

Cuando aplico  **session()->forget('timer')** borra la variable, pero cuando recargo sigue estando la variable **timer**, La única forma que he encontrado hasta el momento para eliminar la variable es borrar las cookies del lado del cliente.

Comment: Has intentado con el helper global? session(['timer' => 'value']);

Comment: Qué más código tienes debajo de ese `if`? Tienes algún `dd()`?

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes con `var_dump($diff, $request->session('timer'));`?

Comment: Utilizar el helper es lo mismo $request->session(); var_dump solo impre las variables tipadas. Al parecer para guardar las variables de sesión no es suficiente con mutarlas en la la instancia. Ademas se deben de guardar por medio del método session()->save();